# Pass a logo to image module

Tags: media

How do I pass the logo on my theme to the image module to create different sizes? I'm using domain access to I can't use

```
<?php print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'path' =>'public://new_ctrl_logo_front1_1.jpg')); ?>
```

as I'm using domain access and using one theme for use on multiple sites. I found this code on another form that works on my theme and need to know if I can pass an image style through it.

```
<?php
if (theme_get_setting('toggle_logo')) {
$image = array(
'path' => theme_get_setting('logo'),
'alt' => 'my logo',
);
print theme('image', $image);}?>
```

Thanks for helping,
Gregory S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

If one needs to obtain "JUST" the filename for theme logo for the active theme for any given domain in a domain access environment (as the OP found he needed to do), then the following code provides the image file name for the theme logo as $img_file.

```
$global $base_url;
img_path = theme_get_setting('logo'); 
$str_to_remove = $base_url . '/sites/default/files/'; 
$img_file = str_replace($str_to_remove, '', $img_path);
```

**Original**

Pass "theme_get_setting('logo')" as the path for the first php script?

```
<?php print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'path' => theme_get_setting('logo'))); ?>
```

or rather - an amalgamation of the two -

```
if (theme_get_setting('toggle_logo')) {
print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'path' => theme_get_setting('logo')));
}
```

Comment: Neither didn't work.

Comment: Echo theme_get_setting('logo'); and post the output.

Comment: `print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'path' => echo 'theme_get_setting('logo')'));` gave me WSOD (white screen of death)

Comment: No. Don't do that. Literally just Echo theme_get_setting('logo') in order to see what it's outputting. Also I see that you've placed 'theme_get_setting('logo') as a string. When you originally tried the code I posted the first time, did you also insert it as a string?

Comment: I can echo and pass it as a string. `<?php $logo_image = theme_get_setting('logo');
print $logo_image; ?>`

Comment: [When you originally tried the code I posted the first time, did you also insert it as a string?] no just as it was posted.

Comment: When you get the string - what value are you getting? I'm curious how /if domain access affects theme_get_setting();

Comment: The above code with $logo_image just passes what's in the logo.

Comment: So it looks like the logo requires URI or absolute path and not a relative path, correct?

Comment: I don't know what "just passes what's in the logo" means. Please try to be specific.

Try using: `theme_get_setting('logo_path')` as in...

`if (theme_get_setting('toggle_logo')) {
print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'path' => theme_get_setting('logo_path')));
}` And for this you may have to pass a second parameter into theme_get_setting, namely the theme name.

Comment: That didn't work either. It looks like the path to the logo requires hard-coding the URI, which I cannot do because of the theme being a domain access multisite. I've found another way to do a logo by creating a form that allows an admin to upload an image.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you found another way - however for anyone who reads upon this on google - don't take the OP's inability to obtain results as a suggestion that this is in anyway impossible. This absolutely does not require hard-coding the URI. The necessary value can be obtained by str_replace, etc. (Although you have to know what values you are obtaining from functions and what values you desire - basic troubleshooting)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25235/discussion-between-john-millnik-and-gregory-schultz).